# Separate a string into a pair of substrings at a special character sequence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to get two string values separated by a special character.
For example, say user types in a search query like

```
japanese->chinese (or with spaces japanese -> chinese).
```

- the spaces between the arrow should not matter. I should still get 'japanese' , 'chinese' even if theres' multiple spaces between the arrow and the two string

The whole string 'japanese -> chinese' will be sent.
From that string, I want to retrieve individual string 'japanese' and 'chinese' to perform some search logic. How would I do that with javascript ? is this possible through regex?

Comment: how would i deal with this? i tried using both. Mohmad answer only works if theres no space between arrow. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `str.split`[`(/\s*->\s*/g)`](https://regex101.com/r/ewTrNp/1/) ... *an optional whitespace (sequence)* followed by **`->`** followed by *an optional whitespace (sequence)* ... the provided examples also show the limitations of your use case.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, I have deleted my answer, sorry for posting an incorrect answer

Comment: @AbitoPrakash ... you wanted to learn, you just could have refactored your code based on my regex and you would have gotten my upvote for your willingness and politeness.

Comment: Will take a note of this while posting answers in the future. Thank you @PeterSeliger

Comment: thank you two and Mohamed. I appreciate the help. Just wandering what the limitation of this approach is as you mentioned previously on @AbitoPrakash's post

Comment: I finally posted my approach as an answer itself. One quote states *"The limitations of this approach are strings that do not strictly follow the pattern the OP is talking about in the requirements."* A link is provided as well in order to demonstrate these exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next provided solution takes the *'whitespace requirement'* into account.

The [limitations of this approach](https://regex101.com/r/ewTrNp/1/) are strings that do not strictly follow the pattern the OP is talking about in the requirements.

The regex itself ... `/\s*->\s*/g` ... matches patterns literally like that ...

- `\s*` ... an optional whitespace (sequence) ... followed by ...
- `->`... followed by ...
- `\s*` ... an optional whitespace (sequence)
- flagged as `global` search(, which within the OP's current requirements was not even necessary)

```js
const test = ' japanese ->chinese ';
const regXSplit = (/\s*->\s*/g);

console.log(
  "' japanese ->chinese '.trim().split(/\s*->\s*/g)",
  test.trim().split(regXSplit)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const str = "japanese->chinese";
const res = str.split("->");

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

res will be an array of string, you don't need regex !